# Monitoring a Twitter stream on a webserver

Tags: django, twitter, tweepy

I wrote a program using Tweepy that I can run on my home computer to monitor a Twitter stream.  The way Tweepy does this is basically to have a while(true) loop always running.  Now what I want to do is link this program into my Django app.  One way I could do this is to leave the Twitter program on the local computer and have it update the database of the server when it receives a message.  However, I was wondering what I need to do run the Twitter program in the background on my server.  I am using Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have discovered with your comment, celery is not ideal - you would  need another long running process to monitor the existing long running process (your client).

Ideally you need a socket that is always open (like the infinite while loop in your client); so wheverver there is data you get a "realtime" view of the twitter feed on the web page.

[Node.js](http://nodejs.org) combined with [SocketIO](http://socket.io/) is designed to solve this, and since a twitter feed realtime viewer is a common case many examples are floating about - [streamie](https://github.com/cramforce/streamie) is one of them.

That combination gives you a javascript client that automatically updates based on data coming; no refresh, ajax polling, cron, etc. required.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) which is a task queue that can perform tasks in the background (i.e. outside the request/response cycle). It also has django integration with [django-celery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery).

You can set it up to perform periodic tasks, i.e. check the twitter stream every 5 minutes using tweetpy and save the results to the db. Alternatively you could set up a task that fires on an operation i.e. when a user clicks something on the webapp, start a background task to scrape twitter.

If you don't want to go to that kind of trouble, you could alternatively just use Cron to perform an operation every X minutes, or a simplified queue app. That said, Celery is well tested and reliable and probably worth the extra effort

Comment: I like the idea of Celery in general, but if the ops utility doesn't need to respond to any triggers from the request/response cycle, and all you are going to do is set and forget a timer, a cron would easily solve the issue. Though +1 on suggesting both here. From the OPs description so far, it doesn't seem like the utility will have any real benefit from living inside the django server process.

Comment: My vote is for the cron job since it's not specifically tied to a view function. I try to use celery only when I have to due to the added complexity.

Comment: Yea, both good points. If it's just working in the background without any link from the user's perspective, then Celery would definitely be overkill

Comment: This task never completes though.  So would I set it to just happen once? Or would I set it to happen every 5 minutes the stop it and restart it?